# Code Fight findClosestPair not returning the correct distance between sum

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to solve a code fights and have everything working except for the following test case:

```
Input:
numbers: [1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 0]
sum: 5
Output:
Run the code to see output
Expected Output:
2
Console Output:
Empty
```

The goal of the code fight is:
*Given an array of integers numbers, we'd like to find the closest pair of elements that add up to sum. Return the distance between the closest pair (absolute difference between the two indices). If there isn't a pair that adds up to sum, return -1.
Example
For numbers = [1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 0] and sum = 5 the output should be findClosestPair(numbers, sum) = 2. 1 and 4 have a sum of 5, but 2 and 3 are closer.
for numbers = [2, 3, 7] and sum = 8 the output should be findClosestPair(numbers, sum) = -1. There are no pairs that have a sum of 8.*

The following function will return all numbers true for all cases except for a subsequent set of numbers is closer. In the example above the 2 and the 3 are closer and should return a distance of 2 but my code picks up the 1 and 4 and stops and returns it. How do I fix it to add the if statement to allow for a smaller distance to be returned?

```
def findClosestPair(numbers, sum):
    num_len = len(numbers)
    distance = 10
    for x in range(num_len):
        for y in range(x+1,num_len):
            if numbers[x] + numbers[y] == sum:
                if distance > abs(y-x):
                    distance = abs(y-x)
            else:
                continue
            return distance
    else:
        return int(-1)
```

This code runs but it takes to long to run.

```
def findClosestPair(numbers, sum):
    num_len = len(numbers)
    distance = 10
    for x in range(num_len):
        for y in range(x+1,num_len):
            if numbers[x] + numbers[y] == sum:
                if distance > abs(y-x):
                    distance = abs(y-x)
    if distance != 10:
        return distance
    else:
        return int(-1)
```

Comment: How could this code produce no output? It's just a function that returns an int. It always returns an int, no matter what. In this case, it will return `3` instead of `2`, but it won't return nothing.

Comment: That is the problem. It is wrong if it returns 3. It must return 2 to be correct. I got the last bit of code to work but it takes too long to run.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `itertools.permutations` then iterate trough it and check if the sum of those two numbers are `sum` or not if it is append it to the new list `l` then iterate trough `l` the use `abs` and in the parameters subtract the two numbers then append it to `newl` then get the minimum value in the pair with the minimum value in `newl`:

```
import itertools                                       
def findClosestPair(numbers, sum):
   l = []
   newl = []
   for x,y in list(itertools.permutations(numbers,2)):
      if x+y == sum:
         l.append((x,y))
   for x,y in l:
      newl.append(abs(int(x-y)))
   if l:
      return min([min(i) for i in l if abs(int(i[0]-i[-1])) == min(newl)])
   else:
      return -1
print(findClosestPair([1,2],5))
```

Output:

```
-1
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to Python and this is a great learning opportunity. I put in your script and got Traceback (most recent call last):
  file.py3 on line ?, in getUserOutputs
    userOutput = _rundazze(testInputs[i])
  file.py3 on line ?, in _rundazze
    return findClosestPair(*_fArgs_tcaexpbeuvep)
  file.py3 on line 23, in findClosestPair
    return min([min(i) for i in l if int(str(i[0]-i[-1]).split('-')[-1]) == min(newl)])
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: I was getting the same error when I tried adding to a list to use min() on it. I don't understand why the error is saying min() arg is an empty sequence. Also, I kind of lost why you appended a string converted to a int. I think that is because in order to use min() you need a list of ints. I also don't understand why you used split but split the list with a '-'. I think the [-1] reverses the list. Please correct what I'm getting wrong. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @KyleLinden How come you get a error it works fine for me

Comment: I know, I'm also trying to understand the code. It has to also work for: numbers: [2, 3, 7] sum: 6 == -1, numbers: [1, 1, 1] sum: 2 == 1, numbers: [6, 5, -3, 2, -5, 1] sum: 1 == 4, numbers: [5, 9, 3, 0, 2] sum: 9 == 2.

Comment: I am getting it to work for the test case findClosestPair([1,0,2,4,3,0],5)

Comment: @KyleLinden Now i understood why you are getting an error, i will try to fix it

Comment: numbers: [6, 5, -3, 2, -5, 1] sum: 1 == -5 instead of 4, numbers: [5, 9, 3, 0, 2] sum: 9 == 0 instead of 2

Comment: @KyleLinden I don't fully understand why numbers: [6, 5, -3, 2, -5, 1] sum: 1 should be 4, and why numbers: [5, 9, 3, 0, 2] sum: 9 should be 2?

Comment: Because the distance between the lowest integers that add up to the sum are 4 and 2. 6+(-5)=1 is a distance of 4 indices between 6 and -5 and 9+0=9 are 2 indices apart. We are looking for the least distance between indices that add up to the sum.

Comment: @KyleLinden the first one i understand but the second i don't really understand, because if it is a new input what does that have to do with the previous input?

Answer (score 0):

That `return distance` is misplaced, you are returning a partial result as soon as you find any entry lower than the current minimum distance.

Correct code for an array of any length, very similar to your second snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def findClosestPair(numbers, sum):
    num_len = len(numbers)
    distance = num_len + 1
    for x in range(num_len):
        for y in range(x+1,num_len):
            if numbers[x] + numbers[y] == sum:
                if distance > abs(y-x):
                    distance = abs(y-x)
    if distance > num_len:
        return int(-1)
    else:
        return distance

n = [ 1, 0, 2 , 4 ,3, 0]

x = findClosestPair(n,5)

print(x)
```

You could return early from within the loops only if `distance == 1`, since you know you will not be able to find any pair closer than that.

A faster way is to check each distance ascendingly, so you can return immediately whenever you find a matching sum:

```
def findClosestPair2(numbers, sum):
    num_len = len(numbers)
    for distance in range(1,num_len-1):
        for x in range(0,num_len-distance):
            if numbers[x] + numbers[x+distance] == sum:
                return distance
    return int(-1)
```